# Warning on using map function with more than 2 parameters in python. (warning pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, pycharm

I encounter strange warnings when I use the map function with more than two parameters on the Phycharm IDE (2017.2.4). As we can see on the picture below, I have warnings saying the arguments passed are incorrect...[image: here]

Note: The mapping given is a simple example to show my problem.

Nevertheless I thing that the formulation of my mapping is correct

```
list(map(lambda x, y, z: x + y + z, [1,1],[2,2],[3,3]))
```

I also tried to defined the lambda form with a def but I have the same results...

Note that the code compiles and gives correct results. But what is the meaning of warnings in this case.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Looks like a bug in PyCharm. Maybe someone did not consider this rare way to call `map`.

Comment: Version **2016.2.3** does not flag it but **2017.1.3** does too.

Comment: "Go home, PyCharm. You're drunk."

Comment: unrelated, but you may want to write your lambda as `lambda *args: sum(args)` instead so it  doesn't break when you add or remove iterables to the `map` call...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers interesting for the example that I given :) But as I said is an example that I give and in practical my lambda  contains if else clause and some parameters of this lambda are fixed